# Simple way to remove special characters and alpha numerical from dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a large dataset with some x rows and y number of columns. one of the columns as words and some unwanted data. That unwanted data is has no specific pattern hence I am finding it difficult to remove that from the dataframe.

```
nonhashtag
['want', 'better', 'than', 'Dhabi,', 'United', 'Arab', 'Emirates']
['Just', 'posted', 'photo', 'Rasim', 'Villa']
['Dhabi', 'International', 'Airport', '(AUH)', '\xd9\x85\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1', '\xd8\xa3\xd8\xa8\xd9\x88', '\xd8\xb8\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a', 'Dhabi']
['just', 'shrug', 'off!', 'Dubai', 'Mall', 'Burj', 'Khalifa']
['out!', 'Cowboy', 'steppin', 'Notorious', 'going', 'sleep!', 'Make', 'happen']
['Buona', 'notte', '\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9', '\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8', '\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84\xd8\xa9', '\xd8\xb3\xd8\xb9\xd9\x8a\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa9!', '\xd8\xa3\xd8\xa8\xd9\x88', '\xd8\xb8\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a', 'Viceroy', 'Hotel,', 'Yas\xe2\x80\xa6']
```

Every character which is not a word is to be removed this is only one column in the large dataset. Column name is `nonhashtag`

What is the simple way to clean the column. straight away remove them or replace with `NAN`

Expected output

```
nonhashtag
    ['want', 'better', 'than', 'Dhabi,', 'United', 'Arab', 'Emirates']
    ['Just', 'posted', 'photo', 'Rasim', 'Villa']
    ['Dhabi', 'International', 'Airport', '(AUH)', 'Dhabi']
    ['just', 'shrug', 'off!', 'Dubai', 'Mall', 'Burj', 'Khalifa']
    ['out!', 'Cowboy', 'steppin', 'Notorious', 'going', 'sleep!', 'Make', 'happen']
    ['Buona', 'notte', 'Viceroy', 'Hotel,']
```

Every `[]` is one row in that particular column so removing of only the `\x and remaining characters` is needed the empty `[]` should be left in the row. Keeping the row is important as other column's that row is filled with needed information.

To write a proper code I couldn't get pass through the input read as I am not able to find a pattern in the dataset to write a regex.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: can you also post your desired data set?

Comment: This looks like the wrong encoding was used to read whatever data you used to populate the dataframe. Are you using Python2? I'm on Python 3, and if I decode the raw bytes being represented in UTF8, it gives reasonable things back (i.e. all the stuff in the Dhabi column seem to be in arabic script, the stuff in buona notte seems to be russian translations of good night and night in cyrillic.

Comment: You can only _guess_ what a word is in natural language, you can never, ever know. As far as regex, it is not the keeper of that knowledge.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Exactly this is language encoding problem and yes I am on Python 2.7

Comment: Well, I can tell you that likely the bytes are encoded in UTF8, because when I decode them with utf8 codec, it's giving back reasonable things... maybe you should consider *not* throwing that data away?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ofcourse I am throwing away valuable data but truly my knowledge with python programming is limited and I am on slow growth process.

Comment: I would *strongly strongly* suggest that you use Python 3, which handles UTF8 data *natively*. That is, `str` are no longer sequences of bytes, they are sequences of unicode code points, and there is a `bytes` data type that corresponds to Python 2 `str`.

Comment: If you are reading this form a csv, using `pandas.read_csv`, pass `encoding='utf8'` as an argument.

Comment: Sure I will use `encoding='utf8'` Migration to python 3 might be a challenge as for now considering the time constraints I have. But I will definitely try to migrate to python 3 as early as possible. Thank you so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I import lot of files and many a times columns names are dirty, they get Unwanted special characters and I don't know which all characters might come. I only want Underscores in column names and no spaces

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()     
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')         
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")    
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
```

Answer (score 12):

Is that what you want?

```
In [71]: df.nonhashtag.apply(' '.join).str.replace('[^A-Za-z\s]+', '') \
           .str.split(expand=False)
Out[71]:
0    [want, better, than, Dhabi, United, Arab, Emir...
1                  [Just, posted, photo, Rasim, Villa]
2          [Dhabi, International, Airport, AUH, Dhabi]
3       [just, shrug, off, Dubai, Mall, Burj, Khalifa]
4    [out, Cowboy, steppin, Notorious, going, sleep...
5                  [Buona, notte, Viceroy, Hotel, Yas]
Name: nonhashtag, dtype: object
```

`'[^A-Za-z\s]+'` - is a RegEx meaning take all characters **except** those:

- with ASCII codes from `A` to `Z`
- from `a` to `z`
- spaces and tabs

So `.str.replace('[^A-Za-z\s]+', '')` will remove all characters except letters belonging to english alphabet, spaces and tabs

Comment: Yes this what exactly I want .. Thank you so much

Comment: @SitzBlogz, please be aware: it's not the same as your desired data set. In my answer all characters except english alphabet and spaces will be removed (including letters with accents, umlauts, etc.)

Comment: I understand the loss .. But did need some solution to work around and I take this as starting.

Comment: @MaxU can you please explain `str.replace('[^A-Za-z\s]+'` I dont understand what's happening there