# Pandas: How to remove numbers and special characters from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all characters except alpha and spaces from a column, but when i am using the code to perform the same, it gives output as `'nan'` in place of `NaN` (Null values)

Input data:

```
col1

ABC ad
YQW \2
AQ4 GH
@34
#45
NaN
```

Expected output:

```
col1

ABC ad
YQW
AQ GH
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Code i have been using:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*)')
```

Later i am using this column to check the condition for `NaN` but its not giving as after executing the above script it changes the `NaN` values to `'nan'`.

Note: without casting to string by `.astype(str)`, my data will get

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @HenryEcker - Using the suggested gives the Error : "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to remove special characters and alpha numerical from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009113/simple-way-to-remove-special-characters-and-alpha-numerical-from-dataframe)

Comment: Because your datatypes are messed up on that column: you got NAs when you read it in, so it isn't 'string' but 'object' type. Go back to the `[pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)/read_excel()` command. Set the dtype on that column to be 'string': `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'col1': 'string'})`. Also define the option `na_values = ...` if you need to.

Comment: And use `df.info()` after the read, to make sure all columns have the dtype you expect them to. Here they don't. The code `df['col1'].astype(str)...` is a telltale.

Comment: Note that we cannot use `.extract()` here and have to use `.replace()` to get rid of the unwanted characters. How about a string like ' ab c1d2@ ef4' ? What regex pattern to use to extract only the alphabets and spaces leaving behind the numbers and special characters ? And don't forget we have to consider the generic cases, not just the sample data here. Can we quote all possible patterns of regex here to handle the infinite numbers of combinations of such alpha, space, number and special character patterns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by the following steps:

1. Firstly, replace `NaN` value by empty string (which we may also get after removing characters and will be converted back to `NaN` afterwards).
2. Cast the column to string type by [`.astype(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for in case some elements are non-strings in the column.
3. Replace non alpha and non blank to empty string by [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex
4. Finally, replace empty string to `NaN` by [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

(Note: The first 2 steps are to special handle for OP's problem of getting `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` although my testing of specially adding integer and float (not integer and float in string but real numeric values) also got no problem without the first 2 steps. Maybe some other special data types!?)  Other users without the same problem can use only the last 2 steps starting with `str.replace()`.

---

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna('').astype(str).str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z ]', '', regex=True).replace('', np.nan, regex=False)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


     col1
0  ABC ad
1    YQW 
2   AQ GH
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
```

---

Note that we cannot use `.extract()` here and have to use `.replace()` to get rid of the unwanted characters. How about a string like ' ab c1d2@ ef4' ? What regex pattern to use to extract only the alphabets and spaces leaving behind the numbers and special characters ? And don't forget we have to consider the generic cases, not just the sample data here. Can we quote all possible patterns of regex here to handle the infinite numbers of combinations of such alpha, space, number and special character patterns ?

Comment: Using the above code gives, AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @Manz  Oh, your column contain non-strings.  See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to extract alphanumerics but exclude numerals. See code below

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].str.extract('(\w+\s\w+[^0-9]|\w+[^0-9])')

    col1
0  ABC ad
1    YQW 
2  AQ4 GH
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
```

Comment: I have some data in Swedish and your code works good but also removes Å, Ä, Ö (å,ä,ö) but I want to keep them. How do modify your code to keep them?